# How to turn on self-service password reset in Azure AD?

Tags: azure

How do I turn on self-service password reset through the Azure AD portal? I cannot find it in the portal?

Answer (score 0):

You can only turn on or turn off the feature with MSOnline module, but other settings must be managed over Portal for now:

```
Set-MsolCompanySettings -SelfServePasswordResetEnabled $True
```

From [Set-MsolCompanySettings documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msolcompanysettings?view=azureadps-1.0#example-1--turns-on-the-self-serve-password-reset-feature)

There is `Get-AzureADDirectorySettingTemplate` in AzureADPreview module, so may be more settings will be available for configuration over PowerShell but there is nothing related to Self-Service Password Reset at the moment.

Comment: @mick32 [MSOnline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/?view=azureadps-1.0) is the 1.0 version of AzureAD powershell module , and [AzureAD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) is the 2.0 version and there is also next coming version [AzureADPreview module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0-preview). As AnsumanBal-MT mentioned, you can post your feedback on [Azure Uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/41465521-add-sspr-to-apis-sdks)

Answer (score 0):

​Enabling SSPR for a OU or group in azure is currently not supported by Powershell cmdlets. The Enablement of SSPR feature is only supported via Azure Portal.

> We can reset password for one user only using powershell.
> **Command :**  Set-AzureADUserPassword -ObjectId  "object-id" -Password $password.

I found an existing idea on this matter in feedback forum for azure. You can upvote the feedback in azure forum and share your additional feedback there for visibility.

**Reference:**

[Azure Feedback SSPR](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/41465521-add-sspr-to-apis-sdks)